# Web to Case Failure Capture

Tags: web2case

Potentially a very quick question...we have lots of websites with lots of different teams responsible for them, so using the out of the box web to case method would be a quick and easy option for us. However I've just realised that if it cannot create the Case it fails silently, unlike web to lead which emails the sys admin with the contents of the form allowing to be keyed in manually. Frustratingly it will send this email if you hit your daily limit.

I am aware of other options rest/soap apis and sites/VF pages which we may well have to do but does anyone know if it possible to capture when a web to case fails to create, without having to have the debug logs running permanently?

Just for clarity I am referring to this feature:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web_to_case.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Web to case emails the the default case owner when you go over the daily limit - see the fifth bullet in this document
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizesupport_web_to_case_notes.htm&language=en_US